# Accessing outer query column in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

For a requirement in our project, I need to convert users ID (concatenated string) into users full name (concatenated string) in Oracle SQL.

Example:

```
Recipients
------------
R23198U,R324I98
```

output:

```
Recipients
------------
Lonnie Lawson, Stan Smith
```

This "Recipient" column is coming from the table email_queue and corresponding users full name are available in Users table. I cannot use JOINs here because these are two different tables and don't have any common field to map.

I tried below SQL to get full name instead of user_name, but it is giving me same value for all the rows.

I am performing these tasks in SQL

1. split the user_names to get individual value from list (using regex)
2. convert each user_name to full_name (from users table)
3. Aggregate the full names into comma separated list

Below is my SQL:

```
SELECT (SELECT Listagg(full_name, ',') 
             within GROUP(ORDER BY full_name) AS CC_Recipients 
    FROM   (SELECT first_name 
                   ||' ' 
                   ||last_name AS full_name 
            FROM   users_table 
            WHERE  user_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT Trim(Regexp_substr( 
                                cc_recipients, 
                                '[^,]+', 1, 
                                                     LEVEL)) 
                                 FROM   dual 
                                 CONNECT BY Regexp_substr( 
                                            cc_recipients, 
                                            '[^,]+', 1, 
                                            LEVEL) IS 
                                            NOT NULL))t) AS cc_rec 
FROM   email_queue 
WHERE  cc_recipients IS NOT NULL;
```

Query Result:

```
CC_REC                      CC_RECIPIENTS
Lonnie Lawson,Stan Smith    R23198U,R324I98
Lonnie Lawson,Stan Smith    R23198U
Lonnie Lawson,Stan Smith    R23198U
Lonnie Lawson,Stan Smith    R23198U
```

Please let me know where is it going wrong and any ideas to improve this code.

Thanks

Comment: Yuck.  My advice is to not store CSV data in your table like this.  The only exception might be if you intend to manage that CSV data from e.g. an app layer like Java or C#, which you are not doing.

Comment: I agree, but this is something which client already has in their database and we got to deal with this issue. any thoughts to manage this through sql?

Comment: I gave you an upvote.  You need a real Oracle guru right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I print only first name, but I hope you will get the idea and add last name easily:

```
select Recipients,
       (select listagg(first_name, ', ') within group (order by first_name) from users_table where user_name in 
        ( select regexp_substr(eq.Recipients,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
          from dual 
          connect by regexp_substr(eq.Recipients, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null  ) )
  from email_queue eq;
```

Comment: But honestly speaking, I would move this complex last and first names calculation into a PL/SQL function to make the query look more understandable.

Comment: This worked and performance of the SQL is good too. I am considering of moving this to PL/SQL. Thanks a bunch for this fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a PL/SQL function for this? Take concatenated user IDs as an input parameter, parse them inside the function, find users full names and return them concatenated.

I think it will be easier to tune the performance of this solution at a scale (if there will be significant data volume on production system) - it's good to keep this in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I am planning to move this to PL/SQL function